# Doctrine createNativeQuery returns no results

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

### tl;dr

I have a working SQL query which returns rows from the SQL commandline, but not when submitted through Doctrine. I think the problem is in how I'm setting the `ResultSetMapper`.  I've read the [docs](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html) about native queries but I must be missing something. What is it?

### Details

### query

The following query run from the SQL commandline produces 1 row:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM 
  StateLogItem s NATURAL JOIN (
    SELECT 
      task_id, 
      MAX(
        COALESCE(updatedAt, createdAt)
      ) d, 
      MAX(id) id 
    FROM 
      StateLogItem 
    WHERE 
      dtype = 'transitionlogitem' 
    GROUP BY 
      task_id
  ) m 
  RIGHT JOIN Task t ON t.id = s.task_id 
WHERE  s.toState = 'started';
```

### results:

```
'20', 1, NULL, 'just because', '2014-07-18 10:49:00', NULL
```

### using `ResultSetMapping`

When I attempt to run the same query via Doctrine in a Symfony EntityRepository (as follows), I get zero rows even though the Symfony profiler indicates that the correct query was successfully run.

```
public function findByActionStatus($status){
    $sql = "SELECT t.id, t.description, t.created_by, t.updated_by, t.createdAt, t.updatedAt
            FROM StateLogItem s
                NATURAL JOIN (
                    SELECT task_id, MAX(COALESCE(updatedAt,createdAt)) d, MAX(id) id
                    FROM StateLogItem
                    WHERE dtype = 'transitionlogitem'
                    GROUP BY task_id
                ) m
                RIGHT JOIN Task t ON t.id=s.task_id
            WHERE s.toState = :status";

    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $rsm = new ResultSetMapping();
    $rsm->addEntityResult('ACCQueueBundle:Task', 't');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('t','t.id','id');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('t','t.created_by','createdBy');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('t','t.updated_by','updatedBy');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('t','t.description','description');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('t','t.createdAt','createdAt');
    $rsm->addFieldResult('t','t.updatedAt','updatedAt');

    $rsm->addJoinedEntityResult('ACCQueueBundle:TransitionLogItem','s','t','transitions'); //tried with and without


    $query = $em->createNativeQuery($sql,$rsm);
    $query->setParameter('status', $status);

    return $query->getResult();

}
```

### entity

The `Task` entity looks like this:

```
namespace ACC\QueueBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use ACC\Traits\BlameableTrait;
use ACC\MainBundle\Entity\Traits\HasDocumentsTrait;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;    


/**
 * Task
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="ACC\QueueBundle\Entity\TaskRepository")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks()
 *
 */
class Task {

    use HasDocumentsTrait;
    use BlameableTrait;
    use TimestampableEntity;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;


    /**
     * @var Transition
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "TransitionLogItem", mappedBy = "task", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {"persist"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"createdAt" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $transitions;

    /**
     * @var Pause
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity = "PauseLogItem", mappedBy = "task", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {"persist"})
     * @ORM\OrderBy({"createdAt" = "ASC"})
     */
    protected $pauses;


    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    protected $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity = "ACC\MainBundle\Entity\Document", cascade={"persist","remove"})
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="Task_Document",
     *  joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="task_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *  inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="document_id", referencedColumnName="id", unique=true)})
     */
    protected $documents;

//etc.
```

### specs:

- PHP 5.5.14
- Doctrine ORM 2.4.4
- Symfony 2.5.2
- symfony environment: dev
- 5.5.34-MariaDB-log

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well I found the problem.  It is caused by `ResultSetMapping` not understanding the query field names I gave it because I included the table prefix. So I can either not include the table prefix,

i.e. change `$rsm->addFieldResult('t','t.id','id');` to `$rsm->addFieldResult('t','id','id');`

or I can alias all the fields:

i.e. change `SELECT t.id, t.description...` to `SELECT t.id AS t_id, t.description AS t_description...`

Answer (score 5):

In my case there was no result because in the SQL query I didn't selected the column "id" of the "main" entity (the one in the FROM clause).